# Velocity 2 putting Map<String, String> in new VelocityContext

Tags: java, velocity

We are looking to upgrade to Velocity 2 for a few of the new features (whitespace gobbling and memory improvements), but I am having a problem with initializing contexts.

Currently we pass configuration for contexts as a Map to the constructor. But this no longer works 2.0, is there some other way to do this that I am missing? Apparently it now wants a Map.

Comment: You can cast to context .

Comment: Can you add the code you tried and failed?